# Android XML file - how to add support for the design tool

Tags: android, xml

When I first started a project in Android under eclipse, I am able to access the Graphical Layout designer, so I fast can design my application. But when I create a new XML file in order to add components to another class I can use this feature, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you have a project with, fore example, 2.1 *with google apis* the editor dont work property. Delete  the google api and try other time